# Removing name if case matches from ArrayList not working

Tags: java, list, algorithm, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to write a program that will remove names from an `ArrayList` if the name has specific value, but I am unable to do this.

```
class UserNamesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("John");
        names.add("Jerry");
        names.add("Jim");
        names.add("Todd");

        for(String name : names) {
            if(name.equals("John")) {
                System.out.println("true");
                names.remove(names.indexOf(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
        at UserNamesTest.main(UserNamesTest.java:13)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Comment: [Use this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to avoid having to iterate within your own code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the iterator not to operate on `List` you're iterating over:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = names.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String name iterator.next();
    if(name.equals("John")) {
        System.out.println("true");
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).
Use `removeIf`  over your list.

```
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("John");
        names.add("Jerry");
        names.add("Jim");
        names.add("Todd");
        names.removeIf(name->name.equals("John"));
```

Or Simply use `Iterator`

```
        Iterator<String> iter = names.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String str = iter.next();
            if (str.equals("John"))
                iter.remove();
        }
```

Note that `Iterator.remove()` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration.[more about iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `Iterator`, with java-8, you could do as below,

```
names = names.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e->e.equals("John")))
             .get(false);
```

Or more readable with filter,

```
names = names.stream()
             .filter(e->e.equals("John"))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'd rather use filter, this way is unreadable. Besides there is an overhead in creating the map holding list of elements that we want and the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 or 11 you could:

```
class UserNamesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("John");
        names.add("Jerry");
        names.add("Jim");
        names.add("Todd");

        List<String> namesWithoutJohn = names.stream()
                .filter(((Predicate<String>)("John"::equals)).negate()) // Java 8
//                .filter(Predicate.not("John"::equals)) // Java 11
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when iterating over a list using an index to remove an item.  Because items get shifted after the move, you can miss some of them.  Here is an example:

```
       ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
       names.add("Jerry");
       names.add("Jim");
       names.add("John");
       names.add("John");
       names.add("Todd");

       for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
           String name = names.get(i);
           if(name.equals("John")) {
               names.remove(i);
           }
       }

       names.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Jerry
Jim
John  <-- wasn't removed
Todd
```

If you are going to to it that way, start with the last item since removing one doesn't affect subsequent positions.

```
       names = new ArrayList<>();
       names.add("Jerry");
       names.add("Jim");
       names.add("John");
       names.add("John");
       names.add("Todd");

       for (int i = names.size() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
           String name = names.get(i);
           if(name.equals("John")) {
               names.remove(i);
           }
       }

       names.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Jerry
Jim
Todd
```

But my preferred way would be using the following:

```
names.removeIf(name->name.equals("John"));
```

It gets all of them with one statement.